# What analysis to use to compare means for when subjects are paired with multiple subjects?

Tags: mean, paired-data

I have 2 sets of data that are connected like below:
[image]

As you see, each ID in set 1 might be connected to at least one ID in set 2 and vice versa. My aim is to compare the values of variable B for different genders (Female, male). I also have several covariates. What type of analysis should I use given that in my case each ID from set 1 is connected to more than one ID in set 2?